# How to insert with conditions in sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm struggling with the duplicate records in sqflite.
Can you guys give me some ways to insert with condition please ?

Answer (score 1):

A little more context would be helpful

There are many ways to prevent duplicates in SQL

One way you could try is adding a unique constraint on the table at the database layer. This way SQL won't even allow a duplicate